# Rails how to get query string from get action in post action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a url like this `http://example.com/myController?key=12345`

In my controller `myController`, i can access the key value with `params[:key]`, but when i submit a form, i want to get that same key in the `create` method, but the `params[:key]` is null.

How can i access `params[:key]` in my post action `create`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the info along by a `hidden_field_tag`.  So your code would be like:

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'key', params[:key]
    # other form code
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might indeed add a hidden field.

If you find yourself adding many of those because you need to have the value available in more and more actions, consider setting it within the session as (e.g.) `session[:current_key]`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden field to your form and set its value to `params[:key]`. Then it will be available in the params you get from the form.

If you're using Simple Form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.input :field_name, :as => :hidden, :input_html => { :value => params[:key] } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new hidden field to pass via params, when you submit the form your action is changed or called again params hash is recreated; what you can do is pass the value via hidden field in the form as follow,

```
<%= simple_form_for @model do |f| %>
  # your remaining form fields
  <%= f.input :field_name, as: :hidden, :input_html: { value: params[:key] } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```